# Exporting javascript script library using DXL exporter to a file using Java

Tags: java, javascript, base64, xpages

I'm trying to export a javascript design element to a file in a Java agent. The problem is that if I set the ForceNoteFormat of the DXL exporter to false, I get a DXL output where I can find the javascript code inside the 'javascript' tag. I can't really use this because it is UTF-8 encoded, and it will break the script if invalid characters are found, like '>' inside a string manipulation.

So my second try was to set ForceNoteFormat to true, the code is then accessable inside the 'rawitemdata' tag, so I decoded the Base64 string and above problem was solved, except it also includes some header information I think.

I found almost the same problem here, but it is about extracting images from base64 decoded DXL : http://lekkimworld.com/2006/03/17/helping_out_a_fellow_blogger_getting_the_actual_bytes_of_an_image_resource_a_lesson_in_the_intricacies_of_dxl_representation.html

Can anyone point me in the right direction how I can get the pure untouched script out of the exported DXL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a different approach. Use the IResource API in Domino Designer. This gives you nice access to the Js without anything sprinkled in. The import/export plugin on OpenNTF does that so look at the source.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. I already used that API with success. But I have to create an eclipse plugin just to export javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan's answer sounds good. Maybe one more thing you could try is the LotusScript code from Andre.

http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=LotusScript%20Gold%20Collection

[*] FileResource: Supports reading and writing file data from file-based design elements such as image, stylesheet, xpage, ... This code will work for current versions, but may need changes once the DXL team adds direct support for representing XPages in descriptive notation. Watch this space.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at that library, sounds promising!